# Pandas pivot table with aggregates from two separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to build a `pivot_table` that contains the difference in values from two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`)along with the agg mean and standard deviation.

contains `df1 =`

```
gender year     statistics    s_values
male   1999  cigarette use       100
male   1999  cellphone use       310
male   1999   internet use       101
male   1999    alcohol use       100
```

contains `df2 =`

```
gender   year     statistics    s_values
female   1999  cigarette use       156
female   1999  cellphone use       198
female   1999   internet use       232
female   1999    alcohol use       243
```

desired output is `my_pivot_table =`

```
year    statistics       male   female  difference   mean    std
1999  cigarette use     100.0    156.0       56.0    128.0   28.0
1999  cellphone use     310.0    198.0      112.0    254.0   56.0
1999   internet use     101.0    232.0       78.0    166.5   65.5
1999    alcohol use     100.0    243.0      143.0    171.5   50.0
```

I merged `df1` and `df2` into one dataframe called `merged_df` I am not sure if this would be the right step towards building the desired pivot table... I am not sure where to go from here the `male` column contains `s_values` from `df1` and the female column contains `s_values` from `df2` contains `merged_df =`

```
gender   year     statistics    s_values
  male   1999  cigarette use       100
  male   1999  cellphone use       310
  male   1999   internet use       101
  male   1999    alcohol use       100
female   1999  cigarette use       156
female   1999  cellphone use       198
female   1999   internet use       232
female   1999    alcohol use       243
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = pd.concat([df1, df2]).pivot(
    index=["year", "statistics"], columns="gender", values="s_values"
)

x["difference"] = (x["male"] - x["female"]).abs()
x["mean"] = x[["male", "female"]].mean(axis=1)
x["std"] = x[["female", "male"]].std(axis=1, ddof=0)
print(x.reset_index().rename_axis("", axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
   year     statistics  female  male  difference   mean   std
0  1999    alcohol use     243   100         143  171.5  71.5
1  1999  cellphone use     198   310         112  254.0  56.0
2  1999  cigarette use     156   100          56  128.0  28.0
3  1999   internet use     232   101         131  166.5  65.5
```